# rotation graphics in post script

Tags: graphics, rotation, postscript

I was wondering how can I rotate a graphic, say a rectangular by certain angle in post script.
Or at least is there any way to draw a very bold ! like, with an angle !?

I have list of sentence around a circle, so each or in 1 direction, and now, I would like to put each in a rectangular and make hyperlink for them.

Answer (score 4):

The power of Postscript is its ruthless pursuit of the ideal of "delayed binding". The implementation of rotations is no exception. It works by making use of a more general tool, the Affine Transformation Matrix.

You can rotate both text and graphics (because text **IS** graphics) because all user specified coordinates are first multiplied through this matrix to produce *device coordinates*.

To perform all the necessary tricks (scaling, rotation, shear, translation), we first have to extend the 2d points to 3d points on the plane z=1 (don't ask me why; read Bill Casselman's *Mathematical Illustrations* or the Adobe Blue Book for more).

```
[ x     [ a b 0 
  y   *   c d 0    =  [ x' y' 1 ] = [ ax+cy+e bx+dy+f 1 ]
  1 ]     e f 1 ]
```

Since the 3rd column of the matrix is always [ 0 0 1 ] it is omitted from the external representation, and the matrix is described in postscript as:

```
[ a b c d e f ]
```

So when you use a coordinate pair for, say, a `moveto` operator, `moveto` first transforms it to device coordinates, x' = ax+by+e, y' = cx+dy+f, before adding a `<</move [x' y']>>` element to the current path.
Change the matrix: change the "meaning" of user coordinates.

The identity matrix is this:

```
[ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ]  % x' = x, y' = y
```

To scale, replace the 1s with x and y scaling factors:

```
[ Sx 0 0 Sy 0 0 ]  % x' = Sx*x, y' = Sy*y
```

To translate, replace e and f with the x and y translation offsets:

```
[ 1 0 0 1 Tx Ty ]  % x' = x+Tx, y' = y+Ty
```

To rotate, replace a,b,c,d with sin and cos scaling and shearing factors:

```
[ cosW sinW -sinW cosW 0 0 ]  % x' = x*cosW-y*sinW, y' = x*sinW+y*cosW, where W is angle(degrees) from x-axis
```

You "install" this matrix with `concat` which takes the Current Tranformation Matrix (CTM), multiplies it by your new matrix, and uses the product as the new CTM. So `translate`, `rotate`, and `scale` are just "convenience functions" which could be implemented like this:

```
/translate { [ 1 0 0 1 7 -2 roll ] concat } def
/scale { [ 3 1 roll 0 0 3 -1 roll 0 0 ] concat } def
/rotate { [ exch dup cos exch sin dup neg 2 index 0 0 ] concat } def
```

Since the CTM is part of the graphics state, you can use the graphics state stack to manipulate your transformations in a hierarchical manner:

```
/box { % x y w h   %create a path in the shape of a box w*h with lower left corner at x,y
    4 2 roll moveto
    exch dup 3 1 roll
    0 rlineto
    0 exch rlineto
    neg 0 rlineto
    closepath
} def

/Courier 10 selectfont
100 100 100 100 box stroke   % draw an oriented box
120 120 moveto (inside) show
gsave
    150 150 translate   % make the center of the box the new 0,0 point
    45 rotate   % rotate CCW 45 degrees
    0 0 100 100 box stroke   % a rotated, shifted box
    20 20 moveto (inside) show
grestore
100 200 100 100 box stroke   % another box, just north of the first, in the original coordinte system
120 220 moveto (inside) show
```

This produces the following image:

[image: Rotating boxes and text]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://xpost.googlecode.com/files/rotbox.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PostScript for a long time, but as I remember you could just use "rotate".

```
                             % do some steps
                             % ...
                             % ...
 20 20 moveto                % go to new position
 30 /Times-Roman SetFont     % select active font
 45 rotate                   % set direction to diagonal
 (Something)show             % print text "Something"
 showpage                    % show it all
```

cheers Kris

Comment: isn't it only for text ? not for figures?

Answer (score 0):

Postscript renders graphics in a given context - and it is this context that can be rotated (or scaled/translated) before drawing. Therefore any element on the image can be transformed as one wishes, all you have to do is to perform the necessary context transforms beforehand.

However, unfortunately, while I can give you an idea of it in this writing, i is a fundamental concept of Postscript, and you won't be able to do any real work in it without understanding that first. I suggest reading a brief tutorial such as the one in http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/postscript/ .

So, the "rotate"  name is a function that does rotate the graphcis context - you use  rotate, before drawing anything you want (rendering text also being "drawing" in this case).

```
%!PS

(Helvetica) findfont 12 scalefont setfont   %select a font to use

300 300 translate    % sets the orign at 300,300 points from the bottom left of page

/start 5  def        % creates variable for keeping track of horizontal position of text

36                   % pushes number of repeats on the stack
{
    start 5 moveto   % places cursor on the starting position
    (postscript) show % renders the string in the starting position, within the current context

    /start  start 3 add def   % increases the value on the variable
   10 rotate         % rotates the context 10 degrees clockwise   (around the 300,300 new origin)
}  repeat           

showpage             % renders whole page
```

Comment: Thanks for link and your code, for me the challenging part is rotating figures, say line or a rectangular ... For instance I would like to tweak your code to draw narrow rectangle instead of "postscript" strings.  So I add some thing like 5 10 moveto , however doesn't work... could you give me a hint !

Comment: Can you make a hyperlink for each rotated sentence please ?!